# Multiple "Add here" buttons due to multiple tabs

Tags: experience-editor, presentation, placeholders

In one specific layout, I have multiple tabs and each tab shows different content/placeholders.

When I'm in Experience Editor mode, Sitecore shows all the "Add here" buttons even for the placeholders that are not visible at the moment.

Example (Experience Editor mode): 
I'm in tab 1 and click "Add a new component", Sitecore displays all the "Add here" buttons for tab 1, tab 2, etc...

I reckon that Sitecore "injects" those buttons in a way that doesn't matter if the content is not visible - it will always have the buttons no matter what.
I'm using Sitecore 9 but I believe this behavior is for all Sitecore versions.

Any ideas how to avoid this?

Comment: Can you add some code snippets of the affected code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same behavior for sitecore 8 when I was working with similar task. I implemented different view for edit mode. Just display tab bodies under each other. For me it was the fastest way for solve this.

Comment: Good suggestion @pblrok. I ended up pretty much using your solution where I show all the different tabs' placeholders in edit mode. I was trying to explore other alternatives like the rendering pipeline or having some sort of event that would trigger a post when in edit mode but to much complexity for this scenario.